# How to modify python3 globals() by key in function imported from another module?

Tags: python, global-variables, metaprogramming, python-3.4

`file1.py`:

```
def test_globals():
    globals()['t']=5
```

in python3 repl:

```
>>> from file1 import *
>>> test_globals()
>>> t
Traceback ....
NameError: name 't' is not defined
>>> def test_globals2(): #local context
        globals()['t'] = 5
>>> test_globals2()
>>> t
5
```

How to fix test_globals function to actually modify `globals()`?

Comment: Generally, you _don't_ want to do this.  Modifying the current module's globals is confusing enough.  Modifying _another_ module's globals is way off the beaten path.  It's probably possible to accomplish in a non-portable way by inspecting the stack, etc, etc.  But before digging into it that deeply, you should probably ask whether this is really something you actually _need_ to do... :-)

Comment: ok, I want to do this to reload functions from changed modules to repl during interactive development process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with what you did is that `from file1 import *` didn't import `t` because it didn't exist. If you repeat the `import` line, it will work:

```
>>> from file1 import *
>>> test_globals()
>>> t
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 't' is not defined
>>> from file1 import *
>>> t
5
```

Another thing that would work:

```
>>> import file1 as f1
>>> f1.t
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 't'
>>> f1.test_globals()
>>> f1.t
5
```

However, if you're only after reloading a module (as you wrote in the comments), consider using [`importlib.reload`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.reload).